# To get total marks into a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

My code is:

```
protected void txttotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtmaths.Text);
     int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtsci.Text);
     int c = Convert.ToInt32(txtenglish.Text);
     int tot = a + b + c;
     txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(tot);
}
```

I am trying get the total marks to a textbox, but it is not working.Can you help me please?

Comment: "not working" is usually not very helpful

Comment: Which controls is this event bound to? From the name it sounds like it's bound to `txttotal` (and then modifying the text of `txttotal` inside)... it should be bound to the 3 subject input boxes instead...

Comment: Why would you set new text in the event handler that handles any TextChanged events?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to change the text in the same textbox that the text is changing, are you sure this is what you want to do?

Wouldn't you want to change the Total when the maths,sci and english values change? if so look at the following.

```
protected void txtmaths_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotals();
}

protected void txtsci_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotals();
}

protected void txtenglish_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotals();
}

protected void UpdateTotals()    
{
   int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtmaths.Text);
   int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtsci.Text);
   int c = Convert.ToInt32(txtenglish.Text);
   int tot = a + b + c;
   txttotal.Text = tot.ToString();
}
```

Comment: And as @rhughes pointed out, if the values in the text boxes are user enterable then you should really be using int.TryParse().

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this method is the even handler for the `TextChanged` event of `txttotal`. I am guessing on "not working" here: You might run into a loop if you change a control in the handler to its changed-event.

You might want to check if you are hitting the handler because of a changed done by the handler.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** there is no problem with the code but it looks you are writing your code inside total textbox `TextChanged` event handler, so who will raise the total textbox `TextChanged` event.

**Solution :** So you need to have some Button like Sumbit and you need to move the above code into Submit button click event handler as below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtmaths.Text);
     int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtsci.Text);
     int c = Convert.ToInt32(txtenglish.Text);
     int tot = a + b + c;
     txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(tot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the code to update `txtTotal` in `txtTotal_TextChanged` event. You need to put the code you have in some method and call it on change of `txtmaths`, `txtsci`, `txtenglish` instead of `txttotal_TextChanged`

```
protected void UpdateTotal()
{
     txttotal.Text = Convert.ToInt32(txtmaths.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtsci.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtenglish.Text);
}  


protected void txtmaths_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      UpdateTotal();
}
```

Comment: How is this solving any problem aside from bad code structure? It might be better structured but it is semantically equivalent.

Comment: I believe he has the code in wrong event and suggested to do it in change of txtmaths, txtsci, txtenglish

Comment: I focused on the problem first, instead of code optimization.

Comment: I am not talking about optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this erroring due to type exceptions.

This is a safer way of doing this with less potential errors:

```
protected void txttotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtmaths.Text, ref a))
        // handle error...

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtsci.Text, ref b))
        // handle error...

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtenglish.Text, ref c))
        // handle error...

    int tot = a + b + c;
    txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(tot);
}
```